# Firebase analytics removes leading zero from property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Firebase Analytics within my React App and I've encountered an issue related to the setUserProperties function.
It seems that when I try to set user properties with leading zeros using this function, the leading zeros are removed from the property value.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
useEffect(() => {
analytics.setUserId(uid)
analytics.setUserProperties({ store_user_id: uid })
analytics.setUserProperties({ retail_id: rid })

}, [rid, uid])
```

In this code, if uid is equal to '001' or any other value with a leading zero, I've noticed that in the Realtime Analytics dashboard, the property is displayed as 1 instead of 001. This behavior of removing leading zeros is not desired and affects the accuracy of the data I'm trying to collect.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions on how to preserve the leading zeros when using setUserProperties in Firebase Analytics for my React App. Thank you in advance for your help!